# Is there a way to experimentally verify the shapes of atomic orbitals?

Tags: orbitals

The shapes of the orbitals as we know, is the interpretation of the Schrödinger equation that calculates the probability distributions of where to find the electrons with a significant probability. But have there been any experiments to verify these shapes practically?

Comment: No, there have been many claims about the experimental verification shapes in very big journals, but they later turned out to be non-sense.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200143/is-there-experimental-verification-of-the-s-p-d-f-orbital-shapes